# JFace TableViewer should react on changing list

Tags: java, data-binding, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

We have the following scenario: an Eclipse 4 RCP-Application should write a log-output. These logs are bound via an OSGi-Service and should be displayed using a JFace TableViewer.

This works well for the first start of this ViewPart. (because there are already logs) If another Plugin writes logs after the View is started, this view should be updated as well. The ArrayList containing the logs for the view (as part of the model) is updated correctly.

The table is setup this way:

```java
@PostConstruct 

public void createControls(Composite parent) {
    b = new TableViewerBuilder(parent);
    b.createColumn("Datum").bindToProperty("time").build();
    b.createColumn("Message").bindToProperty("message").build();
    b.createColumn("Level").bindToProperty("level").build();
    b.createColumn("Bundle").bindToProperty("bundle").build();
    m_bindingContext = initDataBindings();
}
```

The databinding is made this way:

```java
protected DataBindingContext initDataBindings() {
    DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
    input = new WritableList(logItemList.getItems(), LogItem.class);
    ViewerSupport.bind(tableViewer, input, BeanProperties
        .values(new String[] { "time", "message", "level" }));
    return bindingContext;
```

}

We get the items from the list (which is updated correctly) and put them into a WritableList. This list is bound to the TableViewer and displays a timestamp, the message and some kind of loglevel.

The LogItemList is setup this way:

```java
public class LogItemList extends ModelObject {
     [.. stuff ..]
    private List<LogItem> items;

    public List<LogItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void addItem(LoggingItem item) {
        LogItem logItem = new LogItem(item);
        List<LogItem> tmp = items;
        items.add(logItem);

        firePropertyChange("items", tmp, items);
    }
}
```

The `firePropertyChange`-Method is inherited from the `ModelObject`-class.

```java
    public class ModelObject {
        private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = 
             new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, 
            Object oldValue,
            Object newValue) {
          changeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
    }
```

I thought the TableViewer/Databinding reacts on this change-event, but it doesn't.

Has somebody any ideas on how to do this right?

Thanks in advance,
Steffen

Answer (score 2):

`WritableList` does not monitor the list automatically. (How can it as `List` does not have a notification interface?)

The easiest way out is to implement `LogItemList.items` with `WriteableList` instead of `ArrayList`. The downside is that the core model is not as clean as it could/should otherwise be.

Alternatively, you can add a listener to your `LogItemList` that propagates to a `WritableList.fireListChanged(...)`. Maybe a "cleaner" solution, but a little more work as you need to sub-class ´WritableList`.

Or you can implement the core model in terms of EMF and use `EMFObservables.observeList(...)`. Way more work, but actually the way, I would have done it :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

We changed the code a bit and removed the DataBindingContext. Now we just build the columns with the TableBuilder from Ralf Ebert. The bindToProperty()-Method is doing it's job.
If a new Item is added to the LogItemList we fire a propertyChangeEvent and with using the TableBuilder.setInput()-Method the content is loaded into the table.

Cheers, Steffen